# What is the meaning of `int a[6][(2,2)]` array?

Tags: c, arrays

The second dimension of the array is not clear. The size of this array is 48, where `int` is 2 bytes but what is the exact difference between `int a[6][4]` and `int a[6][(2,2)]`?

Comment: Just another case of meaningless, obfuscated code. I have no idea why people are so fascinated with such nonsense and wildly up-vote any topic regarding it...  [What does the comma operator do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c).

Answer (score 14):

> what is the exact difference in `int a[6][4]` and int `a[6][(2,2)]`?

There is a big difference. `int a[6][(2,2)]` is largely equivalent to `int a[6][2]`. The `(2,2)` expression involves the [*comma operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and evaluates to `2`.

The subtle difference (see comment from @Virgile) is that `(2,2)` is not a constant expression in C. So `int a[6][(2,2)]` is really a size 6 array of size 2 *variable length arrays*. So technically, it really is equivalent to

```
int n = 2;
int a[6][n];
```

Comment: Actually, `int a[6][(2,2)]` is not _exactly_ the same as `int a[6][2]`: `(2,2)` is not an integer constant expression (in the sense of section 6.6 of the standard). This means that the former is technically a variable length array which cannot be used everywhere. For instance `gcc` will reject such declaration as a global variable.

Comment: @Virgile That's interesting. It seems to be a constant expression in C++. I clarified this.

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
int a[6][(2,2)]
```

is essentially

```
int a[6][2];
```

**Description:**

As per the  `C11` standard, chapter `§6.5.17`, the comma operator `,`

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

```
int a[6][(2 , 2)];
          ^   ^
          |   |
         [A]  |
             [B]
```

Let's assume, `A` and `B` are the two operands of the `,` operator. Then, sequentially

1. `A` is evaluated to `2` (as a `void expression;`). The result is discarded.
2. `B` is evaluated to `2`. As the result of `,` operator has *right side operand's* type and value, the final result is `2`.

So essentially, `int a[6][(2,2)];` becomes `int a[6][2];`

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[6][(2,2)] = int a[6][2];
```

comma(`,`) operator has a least percedence so you get a array as above.

You can test it out for yourself

```
int main(void) {
int a[6][4];
int b[6][(2,2)];

printf("%d\n",sizeof(int));
printf("%d %d\n",sizeof(a),sizeof(b));
    return 0;
}
```

`int x = (3,4);` so what do you expect the value of `x` to be?

It evaluates to `x=4` the same applies to your array also.